# get value of CHtml::activeDropDownList in yii

Tags: yii, yii-chtml

I have this code

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList(
                            $semaineModel,
                            'libelleSemaine',
                             CHtml::listData(Semaine::findBySql('SELECT * FROM Semaine')->all(), 'idSemine', 'libelleSemaine')
                        ); ?>
```

but why that displays just the last element of the table, and me I have 6 items in this table 'Semaine 1' to 'Semaine 6'
and that code display just 'Semaine 6'.
an idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you   don't nedd CHtml but active dropDownList 
Assiming your Semain model is named Semain

```
    use app\models\Semaine;
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;      

    $semaines=Semaine::find()->all();
    $listSemaines = $listData=ArrayHelper::map($semaines,'idSemine', 'libelleSemaine');
    echo $form->field($model, 'idSemaine')->dropDownList( $listSemaines, 
               ['prompt'=>'Select Semaine...']);
```

Comment: my model Semaine extends  \yii\db\ActiveRecord, and the findAllBySql is not define in this class, when I put it, that dispaly an error `Call to undefined method backend\models\Semaine::findAllBySql()`

Comment: Please explain me your yii framework configuration .. because CHtml is form yii1 and ActiveRecord is from Yii2 while CActiveRecord instead have findAllBySql ...

Comment: yes I use yii 2, and it hadn't CHtml,  I got it (CHtml) from github juste to use the activeDropDownList

Comment: Then if you use Yii2 ... you don't nedd CHtml ... i have update the answer